# Matrix operation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have an *AxB* matrix and two binary column vectors, *Ax1* and *Bx1* in Matlab. 
How can i select the rows of the matrix corresponding to *1* of *Ax1* vector? 
Obviously, I have to do the same operation on the column with the other vector.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, e.g. :

```
 AxB = [1  2   3   4;
        5  6   7   8;
        9  10  11  12];
 Ax1 = [0 1 1];
 Bx1 = [1 0 1 0];

 A_rows = AxB(Ax1 == 1,:);
 B_cols = AxB(:,Bx1 == 1);
```

Results:

```
A_rows:

     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12

B_cols:  

     1     3
     5     7
     9    11
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget `find`? I was about to write something similar using `AxB(find(Ax1==1),:)` etc

Comment: It is not necessary, what I'm performing is called "Logical indexing". If you look at [here](http://www.mathworks.it/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=c34bf68a34ffb29e8814de57cda3) it is stated that `A(A > 2)` is equal to `A(find(A > 2))`

Comment: Perfect! I don't have much feeling with logical indexing yet...
Thanks a lot!